# one dropdown close on other dropdown opening bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation menu which structure goes as:

```
1)Settings
  1.1)settings1
  1.2)settings2 
2)Home
  2.1)home1
      2.1.1) home1.1
  2.2)home2
      2.2.1)home1.2
```

- **step 1** - Now when I open settings, the dropdown appears showing
  1.1settings1 and 1.2 settings2
- **step 2** - After this if I click on home, it's drop-down appears showing 2.1 and 2.2.
- **step 3** - Further when I click home1, it opens 2.1.1.
- **step 4** - and then if I click home2,it opens 2.2.1

Now my concerns are the following:

1. After I click on home menu (1.2), if the settings menu(1.1) is open, it should be closed.
2. If 2.1.1 is open and I click 2.2.1,then 2.1.1 should close.
3. If home is open and inside home home1 is also open with home
   1.1.1,and I click settings, then home should close entirely, ie. home 1.1 should be closed and futher on.

Fiddle url: https://jsfiddle.net/hchawla13/4obzh90c/

Comment: The jsFiddle provided is not working..

Comment: and where is your closenav() function???

Comment: Please edit your fiddle, use formatting, make your question comprehensible

Comment: the new fiddle goes as:https://jsfiddle.net/hchawla13/4obzh90c/

Comment: @HarpreetChawla did you solve your problem?

Comment: no @eugensunic
look at the jsfiddle,u'll see that when u click on home 1,home 1.1 appears,on home 2-home 2.1 appears.Now what i want is when u click on home 2 after home1(ie home 1.1 is open) then home 1 should go inside.
Second,when u click on Home after clicking settings(settings1,2 are open),then home should go inside-also if either home 1or2 is open,that should too go in so that when i next time open home,home 1.1 is inside/closed

Comment: I've come across a thing called event capture and bubble in jquery,I created a div around Home1.1 and 1.2 as class="sub_sample" and applied the same jquery event as that done to class sample,that if has a class in,then remove it.The parent event(of sample) is executed when clicked on sample,then on clicking child-first parent is executed then child(as per event capture),but every time in the if condition for sample class,it just removes the class(it never goes in else condition).Dunno why.